# How can I display annotations for certain features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, labeling, features, annotation

I am trying to display annotations for single features. I know it is possible to display annotations for layers, and for that entire map, but I would like to display them based on a SINGLE selected feature.
example:-

I have a layer called A that is visible on the map, so all the features in it are visible. Now I select a feature, and want to display the annotation for that particular feature not the whole layer; how is this possible?

In my code I am doing this but for the entire layer, but I want it for a single feature, any ideas?

Here is my code which is a method that displays annotations for STRUCTURE features:

```
public static void ToggleXyLabelVisibility(IApplication application,ISchematicLayer layer, ISchematicFeature slctdFtr =null) {
        var doc = application.Document as IMxDocument;
        if (doc != null) {
      // display annotation for the entire layer if no features are selected
            if (slctdFtr == null) {
                var compLayer = layer as ICompositeLayer;
                if (compLayer != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < compLayer.Count; i++) {
                        var geoflay = compLayer.Layer[i] as IGeoFeatureLayer;
                        if (geoflay != null) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < geoflay.AnnotationProperties.Count; j++) {
                                var annotationProperties = geoflay.AnnotationProperties;
                                IElementCollection col1;
                                IElementCollection col2;
                                IAnnotateLayerProperties properties;
                                annotationProperties.QueryItem(j, out properties, out col1, out col2);
                                if (string.Equals(properties.Class, Locationlabel,
                                    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                                    properties.DisplayAnnotation = !properties.DisplayAnnotation;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
            // if features are selected, then display it for those selected features only
            else {
            // CODE GOES HERE WHICH I CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW TO DO
            }
            doc.ActiveView.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try setting `IAnnotateLayerProperties.LabelWhichFeatures` to `esriSelectedFeatures` ?

Comment: here is what I did
      `if (string.Equals(properties.Class, Locationlabel,                                  StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
if(slctStr !=null)
properties.LabelWhichFeatures=esriWhichFeature.esriSelectedFeatures                                    properties.DisplayAnnotation = !properties.DisplayAnnotation;

                                }`

But nothing changes, it applies to all the features not the selected ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set IAnnotateLayerProperties.LabelWhichFeatures to esriSelectedFeatures
Try this!